# How to implement a "make check" to run checkers on my package?

Tags: shell

I would like to be able to quickly run popular Emacs checking utilities on my package, for example:

- checkdoc
- package-lint
- relint
- check-declare
- byte-code-compile

Perhaps some others.

Is there a way to conveniently run these checkers from the command line so I don't need to load up each file (of a multi-file package) and run the checkers on each one?

Comment: A build tool could do this for you, for example with https://doublep.github.io/eldev/, `eldev compile`, `eldev lint` would carry out some of the above.

Comment: A command-line tool to do what you request isn't really a question about Emacs, is it? OK, you could presumably _also_ run such a tool from within Emacs. But the question seems unclear wrt its relation to Emacs.

Comment: @Drew this is about emacs package development, and the command line tool would typically run Emacs.